# inheritance of variables between objects - how to do it better in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, inheritance

This might sound like a newbie question (and probably is) however I am not sure how I should work with this problem:

I create an object like this (js & jquery):

```
var data = [{ "groupName": "G1", "status": "active"}, { "groupName": "G2", "status": "inactive"}, { "groupName": "G3", "status": "active"}]

function game() {
   this.groups = [];
   this.makeGroups = function(group) {
       this.groups.push(group);
   }
    this.getGroupsWithStatus = function (status) {
        return data.filter( group => group.status == status  )
   }
}

function group(key) {
   this.groupKey = key;
   this.showGroupName = function() {
       return this.groupKey
   }
   this.checkPreviousGroup = function () {
     var filtered = myGame.getGroupsWithStatus("active"); // 4. calling instance by its name - is it good?
     var self = this; // 2. making reference to parent object
     var prevGroup;
     $.each(filtered, function(group, key) { // 3. filtering with each - is it necessery? 
          if ( self.groupKey == group.key ) { 
             prevGroup = key - 1;
             return; 
          }
     })
     if ( prevGroup.length ) {
        return prevGroup 
     } else {
        return false 
     }
   }
}

var myGame = new game();
var groups = myGame.groups // 1. global shortcut to groups

var group1 = new group(0);
var group2 = new group(1);
var group3 = new group(2);
```

This code should work, however I am almost sure that it is written in a manner it shouldn't be.
Here are my possible problems.

1. I create shortcut groups to `myGame.groups`. I've been told that I make a global variable this way (and I suppose I want to) but it is possibly dangerous. Is it?
2. I use `var self = this` so I can have a reference to parent object in `$.each()`. Is there any other way to call parent object in the function referring to another "this"?
3. I use here `$.each` to test the expression. Javascript filter function is shorter and better, more readable, but it tests ALL elements and I can break it. In other words if I have 5 elements and I want to filter all elements before 3rd element that has `status == "active"` is there other way to do it?
4. I make only one instance of game class called `myGame`. Should I call it by it's name from other classes or should I do it in other way (i.e. find all instances of `game` class and assign it to variable?)

Kalreg.

Comment: Yes, you should not use jQuery at all here. Just use a plain JS loop, or a more elaborate thing like `find`, `findIndex` or `every`.

Comment: Why are you not using the `data` array anywhere?

Comment: Given you never use the global `groups` "shortcut" variable, why do you create it? Same for `group1` etc. Those codes should probably read just `myGame.makeGroups(new group(0))`.